# Android multiple email attachments using Intent

Tags: android, email, android-intent, attachment

I've been working on Android program to send email with an attachment (image file, audio file, etc) using Intent with `ACTION_SEND`. The program is working when email has a single attachment. I used `Intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)` to attach the designated image file to the mail and it is working fine, the mail can be delivered through the Gmail. However, when I tried to have multiple images attached to the same mail by calling `Intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)` multiple times, it failed to work. None of the attachment show up in the email.

I searched the SDK documentation and Android programming user group about email attachment but cannot find any related info. However, I've discovered that there's another intent constant `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` (available since API level 4) which might meet my requirement.  Based on SDK documentation, it simply states that it deliver multiple data to someone else, it works like `ACTION_SEND`, except the data is multiple. But I still could not figure out the correct usage for this command. I tried to declare intent with `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`, then  call `putExtra(EXTRA_STREAM, uri)` multiple times to attach multiple images, but I got the same erroneous result just like before, none of the attachment show up in the email.

Has anyone tried with `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` and got it working with multiple email attachment?

Comment: I have the same problem. It is not working code. The same problem exists during sending MMS, there is possibility to add only one file. Do you have the some ideas to it in the another way ??

Answer (score 189):

Here is the code you need to create an emailIntent that contains multiple attachments.

```
public static void email(Context context, String emailTo, String emailCC,
    String subject, String emailText, List<String> filePaths)
{
    //need to "send multiple" to get more than one attachment
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, 
        new String[]{emailTo});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, 
        new String[]{emailCC});
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailText);
    //has to be an ArrayList
    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    //convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's
    for (String file : filePaths)
    {
        File fileIn = new File(file);
        Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
        uris.add(u);
    }
    emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
}
```

Comment: you forgot to put the subject and emailText to the intent. otherwise thanks for the code.

Comment: The correct MIME data type should be "text/plain" and not "plain/text": `emailIntent.setType("text/plain");`. If you use "plain/text" Android will force to use GMail as a sender, but if you use "text/plain" it will provide application chooser dialog with Gmail, Facebook, Bluetooth etc. If you would like to propose only mail programs use "text/xml" instead.

Comment: And if you change last line to `context.startActivity(emailIntent);` the checkbox "Use by default for this action" will appear in the application chooser dialog, thus user will be able to select the default application for sending the emails with multiple attachments.

Comment: This example is netting me an "AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?" I've tried passing both the Application and base context to this e-mail method, and both result in the same error.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689581/calling-startactivity-from-outside-of-an-activity) solved it for me, but I'm not sure if I'm escaping an error in a weird way, so I'll leave the previous comment here for anyone who has any idea about it.

Comment: Also, the Subject and Body components aren't being sent: `emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
         emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailText);`

Comment: I just pulled my hair on where did you get that generic `ArrayList` from when I realized this is Java... for those doing it in C#/Xamarin, it works just as well, get rid of the camel casing and write `var uris = new List<Android.OS.IParcelable>();`

Answer (score 31):

`ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` should be the action

and then `emailIntent.setType("text/plain");`

followed by:

```
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
String[] filePaths = new String[] {"sdcard/sample.png", "sdcard/sample.png"};
for (String file : filePaths)
{
    File fileIn = new File(file);
    Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
    uris.add(u);
}
emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 20):

Although this is an old thread, but as it is shown on top on google searches i want to add a small hint to make it complete, hence I stumpled upon it.

It is necessary to make the attached files readable for the mail activity, otherwise they will not be attached. So you have to call somewhere

```
fileIn.setReadable(true, false)
```

Comment: Thank you sir, the mail wasn't able to send the attachments only the mail.

Comment: Thank you, man! I couldn't make the pictures to be sent without this line

Comment: WOW! this answer totally saved my day. If anyone gets "one or more files not attached. limit 20mb" error from gmail app, this fix solves everything. Best tip ever!

Answer (score 19):

Here I found great example http://www.blackmoonit.com/2010/02/filebrowser-send-receive-intents/

you must use

```
final Intent aIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
aIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,theUris);
aIntent.setType(theOverallMIMEtype);
```

Answer (score 4):

For multiple attachments use `PutParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, uris)`where uris variable is a `List<IParcelable>().`
Here's an example:

```
var email = new Intent(Intent.ActionSendMultiple);
    email.SetType("text/plain");
    email.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraEmail, new string[]{emailTo});
    email.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraCc, new string[]{emailCC});

    var uris = new List<IParcelable>();
    filePaths.ForEach(file=> {
        var fileIn = new File(file);
        var uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(fileIn);
        uris.Add(uri);
    });

    email.PutParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, uris);

    context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(email, "Send mail..."));
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Could you share IParcelable class please?