# Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, runtimeexception

I'm using an `AlarmManager` to trigger an intent that broadcasts a signal. The following is my code:

```
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(this, Wakeup.class);
try
{
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);
    Long elapsed +=  // sleep time;
    mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, elapsed, pi);
}
catch(Exception r)
{
    Log.v(TAG, "RunTimeException: " + r);
}
```

I'm calling this code from an `Activity`, so I don't know how I could be getting the following error...

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7557): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.wcc.Wakeup: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

Answer (score 526):

if your android version is below Android - 6 then you need to add this line otherwise it will work above Android - 6.

```
...
Intent i = new Intent(this, Wakeup.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
...
```

Comment: yes this works. but if you want to start multiple instances of the same Activity this does not work. Since the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK will resume the same existing Activity

Comment: Add flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_Multiple_TASKS TO RESOLVE YOUR problem

Comment: Beware, you need this on Android 9+ also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50833599/1000551) for clarifications

Answer (score 60):

For Multiple Instance of the same activity , use the following snippet,

**Note** : This snippet, I am using outside of my `Activity`. Make sure your `AndroidManifest` file doesn't contain `android:launchMode="singleTop|singleInstance"`. if needed, you can change it to `android:launchMode="standard"`.

```
Intent i = new Intent().setClass(mActivity.getApplication(), TestUserProfileScreenActivity.class);  
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);

// Launch the new activity and add the additional flags to the intent
mActivity.getApplication().startActivity(i);
```

This works fine for me. Hope, this saves times for someone. If anybody finds a better way, please share with us.

Comment: Please understand the difference between setFlags() and addFlag() methods. All you are doing now is launching an activity with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. As in the code posted by Cristian below.

Comment: -------------------------------------------------------------------i.addFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
i.addFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
-------------------------------------------------------------------

i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);

Answer (score 57):

[Android Doc](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all#fant-required) says -

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK requirement is now enforced
>
> With Android 9, you cannot start an activity from a non-activity
>   context unless you pass the intent flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. If you
>   attempt to start an activity without passing this flag, the activity
>   does not start, and the system prints a message to the log.
>
> Note: The flag requirement has always been the intended behavior, and
>   was enforced on versions lower than Android 7.0 (API level 24). A bug
>   in Android 7.0 prevented the flag requirement from being enforced.

That means for `(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) || (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P)` it is mandatory to add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` while calling `startActivity()` from outside of an `Activity` context.

So it is better to add flag for all the versions -

```
...
Intent i = new Intent(this, Wakeup.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
...
```

Answer (score 15):

You didn't paste the part where you call `startActivity`, that's the interesting part.

You might be calling `startActivity` in a `Service` context, or in an `Application` context.

Print "this" to log cat before making the `startActivity` call, and see what it refers to, it's sometimes a case of using an inner "this" accidentally.

Comment: This is likely the problem OP is having. I have encountered the same. Launching an activity with getApplicationContext() instead of an existing activity will trigger this error.

Comment: NICE :) I'm quite sure this was the mistake I try to spot the whole evening. Thanks, Mister.

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes this error can occur without an explicit call to `startActivity(...)`. For example, some of you may have seen a stack trace like this in Crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
       at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1597)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1584)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:337)
       at android.text.style.URLSpan.onClick(URLSpan.java:62)
       at android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent(LinkMovementMethod.java:217)
       at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:9522)
       at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8968)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:5303)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2559)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1767)
       at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2866)
       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:67)
       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:67)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2520)
       at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9173)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4706)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4544)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4068)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4121)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4087)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4201)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4095)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4258)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4068)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4121)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4087)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4095)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4068)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6564)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6454)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6425)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6654)
       at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

And you may wonder what you did wrong, since the trace only includes framework code. Well, here's an example of how this can happen. Let's say we're in a fragment.

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
Context activityContext = activity;
Context appContext = activityContext.getApplicationContext();
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(appContext); // whoops!
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, parent, false);
TextView tvWithLinks = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_with_links);

tvWithLinks.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()); // whoops!!
```

Now, when a user clicks on that text view, your app will crash with the stack trace above. This is because the *layout inflater* has a reference to the *application context*, and so therefore your *text view* has an application context. Clicking on that text view *implicitly* calls `appContext.startActivity(...)`.

Final note: I tested this on Android 4, 5, 6, and 7 devices. It only affects 4, 5, and 6. Android 7 devices apparently have no trouble calling `appContext.startActivity(...)`.

I hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing to this line:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, i, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just want to notice that `startActivity` from outside an activity is valid in some android versions (between N and O-MR1) and the interesting point is that it is a bug in android source code!

This is the comment above `startActivity` implementation. See [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#917).

> Calling start activity from outside an activity without FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is
>           generally not allowed, except if the caller specifies the task id the activity should
>           be launched in. **A bug was existed between N and O-MR1 which allowed this to work**.

Comment: what is the solution for that

Answer (score 1):

This same error I have faced in case of getting Notification in latest Android devices 9 and 10.

It depends on Launch mode how you are handling it. Use below code:-
android:launchMode="singleTask"

Add this flag with Intent:-
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have used context for `startActivity`, after changing that with `ActivityName.this` . it solves. I'm using method from util class so this happens.

Hope it help some one.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to open an activity within your app then you can call the startActivity() method with an Intent as parameter. That intent would be the activity that you want to open. 
First you have to create an object of that intent with first parameter to be the context and second parameter to be the targeted activity class.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity_a.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I'm writing as a reviewer because your answer has been flagged for low-quality. The shortcoming of this answer is that there's no explanation of what your code does or of why it solves the problem posed in the question. Would you please add some explanatory comments, bearing in mind that many programmers could read your answer in future for guidance. Thank you!

Comment: When you wnat to open an activity within your app then you can call the startActivity() method with an Intent as parameter. That intent would be the activity that you want to open. First you have to create an object of that intent with first parameter to be the context and second parameter to be the targeted activity class.
Hope this will help.

Comment: OK. But rather than putting that information in a comment you should edit your answer and put it there. I regret belabouring this point but it's important to do this for every answer. Best regards.

Comment: Yes, please include explanations as to why your answer is correct.  We only learn to be better programmers when we learn WHY we do the things we do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code. I have implemented it in a wallpaper api implementation app. In my app specifically when user click on a wallpaper image it will revert it on full screen view.

```
holder.imageView.setOnClickListener {
          val i = Intent(context,FullScreenWallpaper::class.java)
          i.putExtra("raheel", wallpaperModelList2[position])
          i.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
          context.startActivity(i)
      }
```