# Perform action after AsyncTask completes

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm using an AsyncTask to perform a login task. The task connects to a PHP script and the returns a JSON object. The JSON object includes a user_id if the authentication authenticates correctly, it also returns a boolean if the login succeeds.

I want the UI thread to run an activity when the boolean returns true, and a different activity if it returns false.

Can i use `OnExecutePost()` to do this? Can someone guide me on how to do this please?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [onPostExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) is perfect for this. However, note that this method will not be called if your task is canceled, which is a case which you might want to handle similarly to the boolean returning false in a normal workflow.

Comment: Is onPostExecute run on the UI thread? Could i simply do `intent = new Intent(main.this, newIntent.class);` then `startActivity(intent);`?

Comment: I can't seem to get `startActivity()` to run in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9118319/1069068 for launching an Activity from inside an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onPostExecute for it but to handle the case when your task is called use [onCancelled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) to take care of that case