# Is it possible to start an activity in onPostExecute?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need to change my LoginMechanism into an asynchTask, so that it wont throw a android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException in SDK 4.x. Its not clear for me how I can start a new intent in this asynctask. I understand that the work will be done in the doInBackground-Method and this return result will be processed in the onPostExecute method. In this method I tried to start my new activity and my service but it shows me compiler errors

```
The constructor Intent(MainActivity.LoginTask, Class<AttachService>) is undefined
```

and here is the onPostExecute Method

```
        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute( result );
        if (result.equals("")){
            loginError.setText(R.string.login_error);
            loginError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            loginError.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            startService(new Intent(LoginTask.this, AttachService.class));
            Log.d(TAG, "setting status of user " + login.getText().toString() + " to stored for service endpoint  " + service_endpoint_spinner.getSelectedItemId());
            if (appData.getLoggedInUser() == null){
                loggedInUser = DBManager.getInstance().storeUser(user,hashedPw,target, true);
                appData.setLoggedInUser(loggedInUser);
                DBManager.getInstance().setUserStatusToStored(loggedInUser);
            }
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ActionActivity.class));          
        }

    }
```

All the startservice and startActivity methods produces compiler error, can someone explain why. 
Thanks

Comment: You may need to define the context as a local variable for the AsynchTask 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118015/how-to-correctly-start-activity-from-postexecute-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
startActivity(new Intent(Your_Current_Activity.this, ActionActivity.class));
```

**OR**

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActionActivity.class));
```

instead of

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, ActionActivity.class));
```

for starting new activity from onPostExecute

Answer (score 1):

In:

`new Intent(this, ActionActivity.class)`

"**this**" means the AsyncTask object. Use **(your class name).this** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the AsyncTask, this refers to the object, which is an AsyncTask.

You want to refer the parent activity, or the context, so replace it with

```
startActivity(new Intent(ParentActivity.this, ActionActivity.class));
```