# how to know when asynctask is finished

Tags: java, android

```
public class Calculate extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        int a = 1;
                int b = 2

        return a+b;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }

}
```

my app use asynctask class (below), and a  function to call this class, 
my question is how to know when this class is finished ? every time i check, its always Running !

Comment: This code won't even compile..

Comment: @Kon can you explain why this won't compile?

Comment: Missing semicolon in doInBackground method.

Comment: `onPostExecute` is last method to run in `AsynkTask` class, so last line of `onPostExecute` is last line in this class

Comment: If this is a separate file from the `Activity` you can use [an interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648#18517648) to update the `Activity` with a callback to do whatever you want. If it is an inner-class then you can call any method you need in `onPostExecute()` which will be called when `doInBackground()` finishes.

Comment: Also, second `param` of declaration (`AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer>`) is what `onProgressUpdate()` takes so this should be `Void` if you aren't calling `publishProgress()` in `doInBackground()`

Answer (score 1):

In your `onPostExecute(...)` method, you could simply call a method in your caller `Activity` which would set a boolean `terminated_activity` to `true`. You can do this in several ways, most probably the easiest ones are `Intents` combined with a `Handler`, or a local `BroadcastReceiver`.

- An example on `Handler`s and `Intent`s is in an answer I posted today in other question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644670/how-to-get-int-value-from-asynctask/21644732#21644732).
- A nice explaination on local `BroadcastReceiver`s is [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

> onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background computation is passed to this step as a parameter.

Directly from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)