# How to call intent in asynctask, or how to start new activity in onPostExecute?

Tags: mysql, android-studio, android-intent, authentication, android-asynctask

How to call intent in asynctask? or how to start new activity in onPostExecute?

I want to start new activity after check user&password is right.

Please help me, I try to do.It but always goes to a new activity and doesn't check user and password.

MainActivity.java

```css
package com.example.puen.mysqldemo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText UsernameEt ,PasswordEt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        UsernameEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
        PasswordEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);


    }

    public void OnLogin(View view)
    {
        String username = UsernameEt.getText().toString();
        String password = PasswordEt.getText().toString();
        String type = "login";
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
        backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);



    }
    public  void  OpenReg(View view){
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Register.class));

    }

    public  void  getJSONClick(View view){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, getDatabase.class));

    }


}
```

Backgroundwrok.java

```css
package com.example.puen.mysqldemo;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * Created by puen on 4/6/2016.
 */
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx){
        context = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://192.168.10.125/login.php";
        String register_url = "http://192.168.10.125/register.php";

        if(type.equals("login")){
            try {
                String user_name = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else if (type.equals("register")){
            try {
                String name = params[1];
                String surname = params[2];
                String age = params[3];
                String username = params[4];
                String password = params[5];
                URL url = new URL(register_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                +URLEncoder.encode("surname","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(surname,"UTF-8")+"&"
                +URLEncoder.encode("age","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(age,"UTF-8")+"&"
                +URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return null;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118015/how-to-correctly-start-activity-from-postexecute-in-android

Comment: I try to do follow that link. But it not work.
It isn't check user&password. It always go to new activity then click button login.