# Resume activity from broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to resume an activity from within a broadcast receiver's `onReceive()` method as follows:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, TimerSet.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

However the activity (`TimerSet.class`) is recreated instead of resumed. The only recommended solution I found to this problem was to use the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` but I'm already using it.

Also, using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` doesn't fit my use case but I get the following exception when I do not provide it:

```
android:util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an 
Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you 
want?
```

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/3689581/599614

Comment: I don't see how that answers my question.

Comment: @NickMaraston could you find any way for using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT? I can use it for newer versions of Android. But for sdk 16 it has problem.. it errors me needed new task flag.. It's ridicules.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure whether this is exactly your problem or not, but I have a situation where I got a notification and I want to start my app without starting a new instance (if it's already running)
I finally figured out that these will work. The FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK will not start a new instant if the activity has already been running. However, it will add it to the existing stack. Therefore, we can do a FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, so back will bring user to the home screen but not the previous state.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Answer (score 1):

remove FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.
also add this flag ->FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. This would prevent new activity to be created if already present.

Comment: The exception persists upon removing the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

Comment: just then simply add lag ->FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. let the previous flag stay. this worked for me. Else if you want your activity to be singleton, there's another solution to that also.