# How Startintent in another class-- Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want do a app with a class to create buttons dynamically with a for loop.

I call the constructor AND the click listener.

All code except the click listener goes, that does not change the activity that I have, I can do?

```
public BotonPersonalizado(RelativeLayout layoutactual, int id, int posicionX,
        int posicionY, String texto, final Context contexto) {


    Button boton = new Button(contexto);
    boton.setId(id);
    boton.setText(texto);
    boton.setTextSize(10);
    boton.setMinimumHeight(5);
    boton.setHeight(5);
    boton.setWidth(100);
    boton.setX(posicionX);
    boton.setY(posicionY);
    boton.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    layoutactual.addView(boton);
```

I use the context to change and use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for call a new activity

```
    boton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pasarid = v.getId();
            Intent i = new Intent(contexto,Tercero.class);
            i.putExtra("id", pasarid);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
            contexto.startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: is your second activity in the manifest???

Comment: Yes, all the classes are in the manifest

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: What is the name of "this" class?

Comment: already we are in "BotonPersonalizado" is a constructor of the class ---- already i edit the text and put the error

Comment: could you please post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: @CristianCV If Sankar V's answer resolved your problem, please mark it as "Accepted" (rather than editing your question). While you're at it, please rollback your last edit and restore your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pasarid = v.getId(); //i get the ID for the next activity               
                Intent i = new Intent(context,Tercero.class);
            i.putExtra("id", pasarid); //i put the id to intent
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
            context.startActivity(i);


        }
    });

}
```

Have a look into this link:

[Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3689900/1329126)

Comment: @CristianCV could please post the complete stacktrace from logcat?

Comment: @CristianCV I have updated my answer. Really it should solve your problem. Please visit the link to know more about the error

Comment: @CristianCV Kindly remove the answer from question. Revert back your last edit and accept the answer which you found correct. So that other users can find both the problem and the solution

Answer (score 1):

Try To Call Another activity like this,

```
private OnClickListener buttonclicked1 = new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InformationActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    };
```

In Manifest,

```
<activity android:name=".InformationActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
- <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
  </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```