# Start Activity from Non-Activity

Tags: java, android

I have an `Activity` class.

```
public class A extends Activity
{
}
```

Then I have a class that is not an Activity but I want it to start the Activity `A`.

```
public class B
{
    public B()
    {
       Intent I = new Intent(null, A.class);
       i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    }
}
```

The code is take from this question which should work: [Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689581/calling-startactivity-from-outside-of-an-activity)
However, when I run it I never change from my first activity to activity `A`. What am I doing wrong? Should I be listening to the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` inside `A`?

Comment: you must have a context to start an Activity. If you have a context then you can start activity from almost every point

Comment: Are you calling `startActivity()`?

Comment: startActivity can't be called inside of `B` because `B` is not an Activity. @IllegalArgument can you explain context?

Comment: @MikeJohn you can use startActivity in your class b but you need a valid context to do so. context.startActivity(intent);

Comment: @IllegalArgument How do I get this valid context? Is it a reference to class A?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public class B {
Context context;

public B(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

}

public void startNewActivity(String str) {
    try {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Class.forName(str));
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Use case of class B:

```
    B b = new B(A.this);
    b.startNewActivity("MainActivity");//the "MainActivity" is the className of the java class
```

**Note** I find this way wierd and a overkill.

Comment: I might be able to use it if this line `A.class` can be something more generic that would work for other activities. Maybe using `context.class` (that would probably fail.)