# why intent do no go login screen in else block?

Tags: java, android

here intent no go on login class when else condition true, and app get crashed, i don't know why app crashed and if i removed the intent method in else screen then app not crashed , but i want go go login screen when else condition true, what i am missing here pls help me.

```
  package notification;

      //import goes here



     public class GcmMessageHandler extends IntentService {
     PendingIntent alarmIntent;
     GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
     String regid;
     SessionManager session;

    NotificationManager nm;
    static int UniqueID=2154;

    String mes,message,call,detailid,platform,service,alert,userid;
    int  U_ID=0;

    private Handler handler;
    public GcmMessageHandler() {
    super("GcmMessageHandler");
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    handler = new Handler();
   }
  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();


    /**
         * Get stored session data userid from other class
         * */
          userid = "";
          session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext())
          HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
           userid = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_userid);


         if(userid != null && ! userid.trim().isEmpty())
         {
           U_ID = Integer.parseInt(userid);
            Toast.makeText(GcmMessageHandler.this, "converted="+U_ID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }

    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);


    alert = extras.getString("alert");
   message = extras.getString("message");
   call = extras.getString("call");
   detailid = extras.getString("id");
   platform = extras.getString("platform");
   service = extras.getString("service");

   showToast();


   //Log.i("GCM", "Received : (" +messageType+")  "+extras.getString("title"));



    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    nm=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

   }
    public void showToast(){
    handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) @SuppressLint("NewApi") public void run() {

            Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            //builder.setSound(alarmSound);

            long[] vibrate = { 0, 100, 200, 300 };

             NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
           mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                           GcmMessageHandler.this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);



         if(call.equalsIgnoreCase("newsletter")){
              Intent intent = new Intent(GcmMessageHandler.this, Webview_news.class);         
                 intent.putExtra("id",detailid);
                 intent.putExtra("platform",platform);
                 intent.putExtra("service",service);

                  alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(GcmMessageHandler.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);     


        }


         if(U_ID>0){
         if(call.equalsIgnoreCase("tipdetail")){

              Intent intent = new Intent(GcmMessageHandler.this, Selection.class);         
                 intent.putExtra("id",detailid);
                 intent.putExtra("platform",platform);
                 intent.putExtra("service",service);



                  alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(GcmMessageHandler.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);     


            }
         else if(call.equalsIgnoreCase("offers")){
              Intent intent = new Intent(GcmMessageHandler.this, Selection.class);         
                 //intent.putExtra("sms",message);
                 intent.putExtra("id",detailid);
                 intent.putExtra("platform",platform);
                 intent.putExtra("service",service);

               ;

                  alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(GcmMessageHandler.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);     


        }


         }
         else if(userid==null || userid.equals("0")){


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"welcome to login class", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 //Here in intent app goes crashed and not going to login screen, this is my problem 
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(GcmMessageHandler.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
         }




            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = 
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(GcmMessageHandler.this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify)
            .setContentTitle(alert)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
            .bigText(message))

            .setSound(alarmSound)
            //**********************for custom
            .setVibrate(vibrate)
            //**********************for custom

            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentText(call);

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(alarmIntent);
           // Notification note = mBuilder.build();
           // note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

            Notification notification = new Notification();
            notification. defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

            UniqueID++;
            mNotificationManager.notify(UniqueID, mBuilder.build());




        }
     });

}




}
```

In else block when control goes in else condition block then app get crashed,.
If i Remove this " Intent intent2 = new Intent(GcmMessageHandler.this, Login.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);".then app get not crashed but not go login screen, just simply the purpose is that i want goto login screen on else bock.
here i am implementing GCM for Notification, and i am just write here necessary code in question.

here is logcat for errors:

```
11-02 11:16:46.690: D/AndroidRuntime(30389): Shutting down VM
11-02 11:16:46.690: W/dalvikvm(30389): threadid=1: thread exiting with  uncaught exception (group=0x411ae2e8)
11-02 11:16:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(30389): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 11:16:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(30389): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
11-02 11:16:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(30389):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1106)
11-02 11:16:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(30389):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1100)
11-02 11:16:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(30389):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:305)
11-02 11:16:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(30389):    at notification.GcmMessageHandler$1.run(GcmMessageHandler.java:173)
11-02 11:16:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(30389):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-02 11:16:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(30389):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-02 11:16:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(30389):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
11-02 11:16:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(30389):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4952)
11-02 11:16:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(30389):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-02 11:16:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(30389):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-02 11:16:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(30389):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
11-02 11:16:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(30389):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
11-02 11:16:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(30389):    at    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: app got crashed in else block

Comment: What the error you got?

Comment: Can you post the error log?

Comment: Have you defined the activity in `Manifest`?

Comment: `Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want`. Since you are not in an activity, you need to add the flag like it is clearly said.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689581/calling-startactivity-from-outside-of-an-activity)

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent back = new Intent(Activity.this, sample.class);
                         startActivity(back);
                         finish();
```

Give a finish command.i think this is the error for u

Comment: it gives that error "The method Finish() is undefined for the type new Runnable(){}"@Sai S T

Comment: Ya u r using thread.so finish() method can't be work.i will give another suggestion later.

Comment: Give a flag to start activity.

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(this, Wakeup.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);