# java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch activity

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-testing

In my test I need to start activity as singleton. So I use flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`
Here my Espresso's test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class TradersActivityTest {
    private var intent = Intent()

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var tradersIntentTestRule = IntentsTestRule(TradersActivity::class.java, false, false)

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        mockServer = MockWebServer()
        mockServer.start(8081)

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
    }


    @Test
    fun network_clientError_showToast() {
        mockServer.enqueue(MockResponse()
                .setResponseCode(400))
        tradersIntentTestRule.launchActivity(intent) // error here
        onView(withText(R.string.client_error)).inRoot(ToastMatcher()).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
```

But when I start test `network_clientError_showToast` I get error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch activity
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.startActivitySync(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:473)
at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.launchActivity(ActivityTestRule.java:358)
at com.myproject.activity.radersActivityTest.network_clientError_showToast(TradersActivityTest.kt:112)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:61)
at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:531)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:392)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)
Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:672)
at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:659)
at android.app.Instrumentation.startActivitySync(Instrumentation.java:405)
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.access$201(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:99)
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation$4.call(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:449)
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation$4.call(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:446)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689581/calling-startactivity-from-outside-of-an-activity) might help you

Answer (score 0):

You're starting your activity outside of an activity context, so you have to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` along with your other flags:

```
@Before
fun setup() {
    mockServer = MockWebServer()
    mockServer.start(8081)

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
}
```

Comment: intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP + Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) -> I get error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch intent Intent { flg=0x10000000 .TradersActivity } within 45 seconds. Perhaps the main thread has not gone idle within a reasonable amount of time?