# Android Intent: Send an email with attachment

Tags: android, email, android-intent, attachment

I want to send send several files via eMail. I found this 
[Android multiple email attachments using Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264622/android-multiple-email-attachments-using-intent) but it does work and I don't get any error message. It just don't attach the files (I also tried to send just one file but I got the same result).

Did I have overseen something.? Do you have any suggestions?

```
private static void email (Context context, String emailTo, String emailCC, 
    String subject, String emailText, List<String> filePaths)
{
    //need to "send multiple" to get more than one attachment
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    emailIntent.setType("text/xml");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, 
        new String[]{emailTo});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailText);
    //has to be an ArrayList
    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    //convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's
    for (String file : filePaths)
    {
        File fileIn = new File(file);
      //  Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
        Uri u = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "blabla.xml"));
        Log.v("bla", "filepath: " +u.toString());
        uris.add(u);
        Uri b = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "blabla.es"));
        uris.add(b);
        Log.v("bla", "filepath: " +b.toString());
    }
    emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
    context.startActivity(emailIntent);
}
```

LogCat:

```
03-06 16:08:50.940: INFO/ActivityManager(69): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE typ=text/xml cmp=com.android.email/.activity.MessageCompose (has extras) } from pid 436
03-06 16:08:52.130: INFO/ActivityManager(69): Displayed com.android.email/.activity.MessageCompose: +1s118ms
03-06 16:08:52.470: WARN/IInputConnectionWrapper(436): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: Obvious, but, are you sure your file paths are correct and point to actual files?

Comment: Most email programs will not be able to handle `text/xml` MIME types. Moreover, most users cannot read XML. Please consider using `text/plain` or `text/html` email prose instead.

Answer (score 1):

This code is working for me. pdfFiles is of type `ArrayList<Uri>`.

```
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getText(R.string.share_subject));
            CharSequence seq = Html.fromHtml(mOCRText.toString());
            shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, seq);
            shareIntent.setType("application/pdf");

            shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pdfFiles);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getText(R.string.share_chooser_title)));
```