# Can not open URL Android

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-reader

Android beginner, I am trying, for my traineeship, to create an Android app **to open and read a PDF file**. 
Then, the goal is to be able **to email them** and **sign them digitally**. For the moment, I'm just looking to open the file by pressing a button.
Now **my Application is Launched**! I see my pretty 'Open' button, I click it and I get :

> Can not open URL

Well... 
I tried some stuff around `uri`, I try to understand with: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html
but without success...

Have you got any ideas for help me?(my app use has something!)

here are my codes:

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.pdfsigner"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <!--Limites de la version SDK -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="7" />

    <!-- autorisation Internet -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">        
        <activity android:name=".PdfActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">                  
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**PdfActivity.java**

```
package com.example.pdfsigner;

import com.example.pdfsigner.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PdfActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);

        //applicat° du Listener click/button1
        Button b1 = (Button)findViewById( R.id.button1 );
        b1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

  //au click...         
  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
  String surl = "/ENGLISH.pdf";
  String apptype = "PdfSigner/pdf";
  if( openURLWithType( surl, apptype ) == false)
          Toast.makeText( PdfActivity.this, 
       "Echec de Open URL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
            }
        );
    }

    public boolean openURLWithType( String url, String type ) { 

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/R.raw.ENGLISH");

        Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri );
        intent.setDataAndType( uri, type );
        intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );

        try {
                PdfActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                return true;
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e( "LTM" ,"Activity not found: " + url, e);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**activitymain.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".PdfActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="168dp"
        android:text="@string/Ouvrir" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**LOGCAT**

```
06-13 17:33:46.402: E/LTM(17317): Activity not found: /ENGLISH.pdf 06-13 17:33:46.402:                    E/LTM(17317):
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
dat=android.resource://com.example.pdfsigner/R.raw.ENGLISH
typ=PdfSigner/pdf flg=0x4000000 } 06-13 17:33:46.402: E/LTM(17317):
    at
android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1638)
06-13 17:33:46.402: E/LTM(17317):   at
android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1510)
06-13 17:33:46.402: E/LTM(17317):   at
android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3258) 06-13
17:33:46.402: E/LTM(17317):     at
android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3365) 06-13
17:33:46.402: E/LTM(17317):     at
com.example.pdfsigner.PdfActivity.openURLWithType(PdfActivity.java:48)
06-13 17:33:46.402: E/LTM(17317):   at
com.example.pdfsigner.PdfActivity$1.onClick(PdfActivity.java:31) 06-13
17:33:46.402: E/LTM(17317):     at
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3538) 06-13 17:33:46.402:
E/LTM(17317):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14330)
06-13 17:33:46.402: E/LTM(17317):   at
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608) 06-13
17:33:46.402: E/LTM(17317):     at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 06-13
17:33:46.402: E/LTM(17317):     at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 06-13 17:33:46.402:
E/LTM(17317):   at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987) 06-13
17:33:46.402: E/LTM(17317):     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-13
17:33:46.402: E/LTM(17317):     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 06-13 17:33:46.402:
E/LTM(17317):   at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-13 17:33:46.402: E/LTM(17317):   at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 06-13
17:33:46.402: E/LTM(17317):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
Method) 06-13 17:33:49.915: D/memalloc(17317): /dev/pmem: Unmapping
buffer base:0x4ca72000 size:3694592 offset:3645440
```

thanks!

Comment: Can you open pdf files outside of your app on your device?

Comment: @Krylez: yes via adobe reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for sending PDF file from email look here [Android Intent: Send an email with attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587559/android-intent-send-an-email-with-attachment)

this Q help you to understand uri 
[What is the difference between a URI, a URL and a URN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/whats-the-difference-between-a-uri-and-a-url)

[here you find how to create a BROWSE button, which when you will click, it will open up the SDCARD, you will select a File and in result you will get the File Name and File path of the selected one. to find the uri address you can use Log.d methood (go to the last answar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore)

The general structure looks like :

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/example.pdf");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),”application/pdf”);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I do not understand the relationship between my code and your (especially PICK_REQUEST_CODE). I think, actually, I don't succeed to include what it should do

Comment: What is the address of the PDF file?? I mean what his name? and in which folders it located?  are you look at the third link? open this link and look at the last answer this what you need

Comment: I have put it(ENGLISH.pdf) in phone memory at the root AND on /SDcard at the root too.
I have tried your 'look over button' and when I launch it, the app ask me with how else app I want to run it this last one

Answer (score 0):

So the first problem is that you're asking another app to open a file in your raw resources folder. For security reasons, this is not possible. The receiving app (Adobe Reader in this case) needs the file to be in a place that's not protected. You can copy it to the external public storage area and then open an intent on the copied file. Keep in mind that you should not do the copying on the UI thread and you shouldn't do it every time, only if the file doesn't exist.

The second problem is that you haven't specified a MIME type for the Intent. Make sure you set it to "application/pdf".

```
private void openPDF() {
    final InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.english);
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> () {
        File outDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + getPackageName() + "/.temp");
        File outFile = new File(outDir, "english.pdf");
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(outFile);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            if (!outFile.exists()) {
                outDir.mkdirs();
                OutputStream out;
                try {
                    out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                    copyPDF(in, out);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();

}
private void copyPDF(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```