# image put into ImageView from taken picture not always showing up

Tags: android, imageview, android-camera, android-camera-intent

An image taken from the camera doesn't always show up in my `ImageView`. It seems like it is random when it wants to show up. Why is it doing this?

**Activity that takes picture**

```
private void takePicture() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PICTURE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    String spokenText;

    // Handles picture taking after finished
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        ImageView imageResult = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result_image);
        imageResult.setImageBitmap(image);

        ImageHandler imageHandler = new ImageHandler(this);
        imageHandler.writeToFile(image, step.getChecklistId(), step.getOrder());

        step.setImageFilename(imageHandler.getFilename(step.getChecklistId(), step.getOrder()));
        finishStep();
    }
}
```

**XML to show picture**

```
<ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/result_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/taken_img_desc" />
```

Comment: intent extra data return for you the URi (place where the camera put the image)that you can assign it for the imageview directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using notifyDataSetChanged for your adapter?
Is your view being refreshed?  Try .invalidate();

Comment: Just need to `.invalidate()`. Thank you!

Comment: I have this same problem. where do I get invalidate before or after setting the image? I tried both but still get the random result.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing: You might experience that the camera intent does not return an image or an uri to an image. I created a wrapper to help you with that. See the whole discussion on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019165/summary-take-a-picture-utilizing-camera-intent-and-display-the-photo-with-corre) or find the code on [github](https://github.com/ralfgehrer/AndroidCameraUtil).