# Can I open Google Camera App at activity?

Tags: android, camera

In my activity I want to open the Google Camera App to take a photo and `setResult` to my Activity.
I'm using `startActivityForResult()`

Can I do that?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.GoogleCamera

Comment: possible duplicate of [Summary: Take a picture utilizing Camera Intent and display the photo with correct orientation (works on hopefully all devices)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019165/summary-take-a-picture-utilizing-camera-intent-and-display-the-photo-with-corre)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out that post: 
[Summary: Take a picture utilizing Camera Intent and display the photo with correct orientation (works on hopefully all devices)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019165/summary-take-a-picture-utilizing-camera-intent-and-display-the-photo-with-corre)

And find some sample code here: https://github.com/ralfgehrer/AndroidCameraUtil

Answer (score 0):

Try using package manager and open google camera application then capture a photo using it.then find the default location where it stores the files.and retrieve the file.