# Send Several Bitmaps in a zip folder as attachment

Tags: android, email, bitmap, zip, email-attachments

i have several bitmaps which needs to be emailed. the bitmaps i have to send are created from another bitmap using the below code :

```
Bitmap resultingBitmap = createScaledBitmap (sourceBitmap, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, false);
```

i don't need to email the original bitmap(sourceBitmap in the above code). but i want to email the bitmap resulted from above code (resultingBitmap ). of course not just that one, but several other bitmaps which resulted from the above equation. i want to zip them and email them. i have found code for sending image if it is stored in internal memory or sd card. there they use the path of the image and the following code to send it :

```
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"fake@fake.edu"});
   i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"On The Job");
   //Log.d("URI@!@#!#!@##!", Uri.fromFile(pic).toString() + "   " + pic.exists());
   i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(myPhoto.getPath())));

   i.setType("image/png");
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Share you on the jobing"));
```

But here i dont have any path for the resultingBitmap and i dont want to store the resultingBitmap in app's internal folder or sdcard as it would consume unnecessary memory. so please help me out !

Answer (score 0):

You will need to temporarily save them as files so you can email but can delete them after sending. there is a command to delete files in your internal folder in android `context.deleteFile()`

[Reference1](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

[Reference2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#deleteFile(java.lang.String))

[this is for attaching them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264622/android-multiple-email-attachments-using-intent)