# android BCC is not working for email

Tags: android

```
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC,
               new String[] {"postcards@in-touchmobile.com"});
```

I have tried with this code, but bcc can not include in my gmail application.

My full code is

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
                            android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    emailIntent.putExtra(
                            Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                            new String[] { Constants.EMAIL });
                    emailIntent.putExtra(
                            android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                            Html.fromHtml(str));
                    emailIntent.putExtra(
                            android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC,
                            new String[] { "postcards@in-touchmobile.com" });
                    emailIntent.putExtra(
                            android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                            Constants.Subject);

                    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                    uris.add(screenshotUri);
                    emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(
                            Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                            uris);
                    startActivity(emailIntent);
                    startActivity(emailIntent);
```

I have changed my code like above one..but still not working..

Comment: please make sure that wherever you are setting and sending string data for sake of consistence use .toString() method. in yours code  emailIntent.setType("image/png"); is there  are you sending images? please set emailIntent.setType("text/html"); as well and have a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in this manner

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
emailIntent.setType("application/image");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{strEmail}); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Test Subject"); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "From My App"); 
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/Myimage.jpeg"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Must do this thing `emailIntent.setType("application/image");`

Checked and let me know

Comment: It's my pleasure that my little help solve you issues. Thanks

Comment: Where's the `Intent.EXTRA_BCC`?

Answer (score 0):

change the type of `Intent` from `image/png` and `application/octet-stream` to `plain/text` like

```
  emainIntent.setType("plain/text");
```

and for attaching files to email see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264622/android-multiple-email-attachments-using-intent)

Comment: bcc still not coming in my gmail app.. i have change my code according to above link..

Comment: @KomalSorathiya could you try changing type to plain/text from text/plain and sorry. this is the help upto I can do.