# ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE email attachments

Tags: android, email

I am trying to send Multiple Attachments in email using Intent ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE and want to Invoke only E-mail apps (google,yahoo,emalclient etc)

When is use below piece of code in S4 & S5 always Email-client gets invoked.

But same piece of code invokes Gmail,yahoo,email-client and other email apps in S3 & nexus phones.

Is there any Limitation in s4,s5 to invoke ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE?

---

```
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Log_file");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "TEXT");
    emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uris);
    emailIntent.setClassName("com.android.email",
            "com.android.email.activity.MessageCompose");
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,
            "Sending multiple attachment"), 12345);
```

---

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264622/android-multiple-email-attachments-using-intent