# Attaching multiple images to mail Composer

Tags: android, email, uri, email-attachments

How can I attach multiple images to mail Composer.

```
 final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 emailIntent.setType("*/*");
 ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
            for (int i = 1; i < alBitmap.size(); i++) {
                strFile = strFile + "/" + i + ".jpg";
                File fileIn = new File(strFile);
                Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
                uris.add(u);
            }
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
 emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
 this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

But, It gives following error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable.
```

Can anybody tell me whats the Solution ? I have also used putArrayListExtra instead of putExtra.

Comment: Refers these links http://android-er.blogspot.hk/2012/10/start-activity-to-send-multi-images.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android multiple email attachments using Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264622/android-multiple-email-attachments-using-intent)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE). Or, better yet, a builder that will create share Intents for you:

- [`ShareCompat.IntentBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.html)
- [`ShareIntentBuilder`](https://github.com/cketti/ShareIntentBuilder)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever got your problem fixed, but you're close. Change `emailIntent.putExtra` to `emailIntent.putParcelableArralyListExtra` and leave everything else the same.