# Android Marshmallow sending multiple files in gmail with intent

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail, android-6.0-marshmallow, permission-denied

I'm trying to send email with intent by call explicitly GMAIL in my app. It was working fine on all devices but now I got crashes on Android 6 Marshmallow devices. The problem I'm receiving is:

```
12-14 00:02:55.365: E/AndroidRuntime(18570): Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo, iconPack:com.cyngn.hexoicons, fontPkg:com.cyngn.hexo, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo}
12-14 00:02:55.365: E/AndroidRuntime(18570): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE typ=image/* flg=0x3 cmp=com.google.android.gm/.ComposeActivityGmail clip={image/* U:file:///storage/emulated/0/Mydir/myfile20161213105548.jpg} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{cc9833c 18570:com.myappdr/u0a341} (pid=18570, uid=10341) not exported from uid 10050
12-14 00:02:55.365: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
12-14 00:02:55.365: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
12-14 00:02:55.365: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2677)
12-14 00:02:55.365: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1509)
12-14 00:02:55.365: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3930)
12-14 00:02:55.365: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3890)
12-14 00:02:55.365: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4213)
12-14 00:02:55.365: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4181)
12-14 00:02:55.365: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at com.myapp.SendGmail.onClick(SendGmail.java:222)
12-14 00:02:55.365: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:163)
12-14 00:02:55.365: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-14 00:02:55.365: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-14 00:02:55.365: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
12-14 00:02:55.365: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-14 00:02:55.365: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
12-14 00:02:55.365: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here are the permissions I have in my Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And here is how I'm sending the mail in my source:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "email@email.com" });
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getResources().getString(R.string.mail_title));
emailIntent.setType("image/*");

ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

for (Map.Entry<CartElement,Integer> c : SingletonShoppingCart.getInstance(null).get_Cart().entrySet()){
    if ((c.getKey().getImgPath() !=null) || (!c.getKey().getImgPath().isEmpty())){
        uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(c.getKey().getImgPath())));
    }
}

emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,strMailMsg);
emailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace.

Comment: Use ACTION_SEND instead.

Comment: I've added the whole stack trace. I'm currently able to reproduce it on my OnePlusOne phone which uses CianogenMod but the crashes in Developer Console are from Marshmallow.

Comment: @greenapps The problem appears with ACTION_SEND either. I'm using ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE in my current update which is not published but I got the error on the current play store version also.

Comment: You should ask the user for permissions to read external storage on marshmellow. Google for run time permisions. You have a parcel read exception. Or go to the settings for your app and switch the storage permission on.

Comment: I had the same question. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264622/android-multiple-email-attachments-using-intent) post helped me.

Answer (score 0):

`FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` doesn't work with file URIs such as those generated from `Uri.fromFile()`. You have to use content:// URIs such as from [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html).

Comment: I've tried but it does not work if I stick to only calling gmail app.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
emailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
```

Delete it, because that is not an exported activity. That activity is available for *Gmail* to start, but not for third-parties to start.

Moreover, [share where the user wants](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/06/28/share-where-the-user-wants.html). Not all Android users use Gmail.

Long term, you will also need to address [Ian Lake's concern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41131413/115145), as your code will fail on Android 7.0+ devices, once you raise your `targetSdkVersion` to 24 or higher.

Comment: What should I do if I want the users to explicitly use Gmail app only?