# How to attach a file while sending email?

Tags: android, attachment

I'm currently trying to create an app that will take a picture from the gallery and then attach that picture to an email that will be going to an email address. I also can't understand on how to add multiple picture choosing from the gallery.

```
Here is my MainActivity

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText editTextEmail, editTextSubject, editTextMessage;
    Button btnSend, btnAttachment;
    String email, subject, message, attachmentFile;
    Uri URI = null;
    private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 0;
    private static final int READ_FROM_GALLERY= 1;
    int columnIndex;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTo);
        editTextSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSubject);
        editTextMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);
        btnAttachment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAttachment);
        btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);

        btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnAttachment.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            /**
             * Get Path
             */
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                } else {
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                        Toast.makeText(this,
                                "Need access to open file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                READ_FROM_GALLERY);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                attachmentFile = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                Log.e("Attachment Path:", attachmentFile);
                URI = Uri.parse("file://" + attachmentFile);
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == btnAttachment) {
            openGallery();

        }
        if (v == btnSend) {
            try {
                email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
                subject = editTextSubject.getText().toString();
                message = editTextMessage.getText().toString();

                final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
                        android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                        new String[] { email });
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                        subject);
                if (URI != null) {
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, URI);
                }
                emailIntent
                        .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
                this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,
                        "Sending email..."));

            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Request failed try again: " + t.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }

    public void openGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"),
                PICK_FROM_GALLERY);

    }

}
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264622/android-multiple-email-attachments-using-intent

Answer (score 0):

> emailIntent.setType("plain/text");

In your code change the above line to -

> emailIntent.setType("image/png");